# Python Math Giving Incorrect Output

Tags: python, math

Python is being weird again. When I put `5 * (40 ^ 2) + 50 * 40 + 100` it returns 2310. But on a calculator its 10100. I don't know why Python is making this mistake nor how to fix it. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: `^` is not `**` ... you are using a binary XOR of 40 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will write

```
print( 5 * 40 ** 2 + 50 * 40 + 100 )
```

you will get the expected result.

```
10100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

5 * (40 ** 2) + 50 * 40 + 100